# Using dbml file with visual studio

Tags: linq-to-sql, dbml

I am developing an asp.net application where some dbml files have been created. When I click on a dbml file called "Test.dbml" and that I unfold it, I get the three following files :

```
Test.cs
Test.dbml.layout
Test.designer.cs
```

However when I create a new dbml file and that I unfold it, I only get the two following files :

```
Me.dbml.layout
Me.designer.cs
```

I don't understand why I don't get the Me.cs like the existing dbml.

I only have access to the old code, not to the developper who code it so I cannot ask him the question.

Thanks in advance foryour help.

Answer (score 1):

By default VS generates a .dbml.layout (visual layout) and .designer.cs (C# generated code) in addition to the .dbml file (XML definition of the mappings)

If you were to put your code in the .designer.cs file it would get lost so VS can also generate a .cs file for you to put your code in.

Simply right-click on the DBML and choose View Code.

At compile time the .cs and .designer.cs are effectively merged together as they are partial classes (the partial keyword needs to be on the class definitions)